# Rider Xamarin iOS error "application bundle was not generated after deployment"

Tags: ios, xamarin, rider

I'm trying to switch from VS for Mac to Rider. My Xamarin.Forms project compiles and deploys on VS for Mac on both iOS and Android. Now I've opened the project in rider and it works great for the Android app, but when I try to run the iOS app, I get this error (after a successful build):

```
Application bundle was not generated after deployment
```

I've tried clean & rebuild, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, this is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15514) with the latest release (2018.1). Already fixed and waiting to be made public as part of 2018.1.1 later this month. The only current workaround that I know is to revert to 2017.3.

Comment: I'm on 2018.1.4 and still getting this issue.  I'm using an automatic setting/default setting for the provisioning profile, this might be why.

Comment: I'm now experiencing this issue on Rider (2020.2.3) and XCode (Version 12.0 (12A7209)).

Comment: @RyanBrookePayne You may want to report this to JetBrains at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/rider. Chances are you'll get better support there.

Comment: @JuraGorohovsky I found an existing issue with a workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-50673. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me today on Mac OS with the release of XCode 12.0, So what fixed it for me was to TOTALLY uninstall XCode and re down the last version I had installed, V11.6 from apple developers site https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?&name=Xcode. After that Rider will now run the iOS simulator as normal.

I guess the  lesson learned is to not just update XCode until a few weeks, because I think Jetbrains need to catch up and release a newer version that works with the newer version of XCode. Of course if you need to test your app with the latest new version of iOS, then I guess you can still use VS for Mac as that still worked fine for me, but I need Rider to code, VS just doesn't do it for me at the moment

Update:
I upgraded to XCode 12 today (3/10/2020) and all seems to be working fine..

Another possible work around if it doesn't work maybe: [youtrack Jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-50673)

Comment: This is happening again: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-51140. Your advice rings true.

Comment: looks like the workaround for now is disabling device-specific builds

Answer (score 3):

Tested today.

Download the last released version directly from their website.

Now is launching iOS devices.

[Rider 2.2.4](https://www.jetbrains.com/es-es/rider/download/#section=mac)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you select **iPhoneSimulator** for your platform type under your configurations.

[image]

If you don't, you may also get the `Application bundle was not generated after deployment` message.

[source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-71654/Application-bundle-wasnt-generated-after-deployment#focus=Comments-27-5608209.0-0)

Comment: This! This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This now works for me in the 2018.2 EAP build.

Answer (score 0):

See [RIDER-98741](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-98741/Application-bundle-wasnt-generated-after-deployment-when-trying-to-run-debug-iOS-app-from-Windows-machine) for the current reason and workaround for this bug in Rider.

Basically, the cause for this issue is, that Rider is generating the `BuildSessionId` hash incorrectly and therefore is looking for the wrong directories.

As a **workaround**, add the following target to your project file:

```xml
<!-- Original parameter: TargetFramework="$(TargetFramework)"
     See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-98741/Application-bundle-wasnt-generated-after-deployment-when-trying-to-run-debug-iOS-app-from-Windows-machine -->
<Target Name="_GenerateBuildSessionIdOverride"
        Condition="'$(IsRemoteBuild)' == 'true'"
        AfterTargets="_GenerateBuildSessionId"
        BeforeTargets="_SayHello">
    <GenerateBuildSessionId MessagingVersion="$(MessagingVersion)"
                            TargetFramework=""
                            ProjectFullPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
                            ProjectName="$(MSBuildProjectName)"
                            VisualStudioProcessId="$(VisualStudioProcessId)">
        <Output TaskParameter="BuildSessionId" PropertyName="BuildSessionId" />
        <Output TaskParameter="BuildAppName" PropertyName="BuildAppName" />
    </GenerateBuildSessionId>
</Target>
```